# Displaying content based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I’m pretty new to `backbonejs` and i’m trying to create a basic application.

The application is something like this:

I have 5 sections: `A, B, C, D and E`

Each section has 2 radio buttons.

```
Section A - Radio1, Radio2
Section B - Radio3, Radio4
Section C - Radio5, Radio6
Section D - Radio7, Radio8
Section E - Radio9, Radio10
```

Depending on what radio button is selected, I need to display a section (previous sections must also display)

I have had a look at maybe using a model to determine which radio was selected and also what section is displayed. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Can you add some more details as to what determines which section is displayed? Is it something like if *radio1* is selected then *section b* is displayed and if *radio2* then *section c*...? Are the sections that need to be displayed only based on the radio buttons or also which section is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var State = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        isOn: false
    }
});
var Section = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: State,
    events: {
        'change [type="checkbox"]': function (event) {
            var $checkbox = $(event.target);
            this.model.set("isOn", $checkbox.is(":checked"));
            this.model.get("dispatcher").trigger("toggle", this.model.get("id"));
        }
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change:isOn", function (model, isOn) {
            if ( isOn ) {
                this.$el.find(".section").show();
                this.$el.find("input").prop("checked", true);
            }
            else {
                this.$el.find(".section").hide();
                this.$el.find("input").prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(dispatcher, "toggle", function (id) {
            if ( this.model.get("id") < id ) {
                this.model.set("isOn", true);
            }
            if ( this.model.get("id") > id ) {
                this.model.set("isOn", false);
            }
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html('<div>' + this.model.get("name") + '</div><input type="checkbox"><div class="section" style="min-height:100px; background-color:grey; display:none;"></div>');
        this.$el.appendTo("body");
    }
});
var dispatcher = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
_.each([
    {id: 1, name: "A", isOn: false, dispatcher: dispatcher},
    {id: 2, name: "B", isOn: false, dispatcher: dispatcher},
    {id: 3, name: "C", isOn: false, dispatcher: dispatcher},
    {id: 4, name: "D", isOn: false, dispatcher: dispatcher},
    {id: 5, name: "E", isOn: false, dispatcher: dispatcher}
], function (item) {
    var view = new Section({model: new State(item)});
    view.render();
});
```

I didn't understand the meaning of two radio.. so I used checkbox per section.. Hope this will uncover some basics of backbone.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to the above

Answer (score 0):

Yes this approach will work. I recommend if you need to communicate between views to use models via events - this will generally result in better architecture (your views will be more decoupled).

You can react to the `change` event in the view (using the `events` hash) and update an attribute on a model for each group, e.g. `this.model.set('termsAccepted', true/false)` then as long as the other view(s) have access to this model you can react to the change event of that attribute, e.g. `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:termsAccepted', this.onTermsAcceptedChange)`.

Comment: Dominic Tobias do you have any examples? As I said I'm pretty new to backbone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There may be a very simple solution to your objective. If you monitor the radio-button state via a javascript function, then you can use that function to change a class statement for the parent div. In CSS, you can then define actions to hide or display a div based on it's class. This would only take a few lines of javascript and a few lines of CSS. 
For example, [this example in codepen](http://codepen.io/rddill-IBM/pen/XmrmyX) shows a way to accomplish the hide/show for a variably sized div. The number of divs in this approach is arbitrary - you can have as many or few as you like, and the only action required of the user is to click on the header to expand or collapse the associated div. 
In this example, clicking on the header acts as a toggle to expand or collapse the associated div. The example is set up so that only one div is expanded at a time and clicking on a different header automatically collapses any open div so that only one div is open at a time. If you do not want that behavior, just remove the for loop in the `accOff()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda like a choose-your-own-adventure, ya sipher_z?

I advise using the Backbone Router with route parameters storing the current state, that is, which section is currently showing.

Each component of the view should be a `Backbone.View.extend({...})`. Components might be Section and Radio.

On each Radio button, in HTML, put a `data-go-to` attribute, with a value of the section to go to next. Then, in your RadioView code, put a click event. When clicked, extract this `data-go-to`, and do something like `location.hash = '/section/' + section` to trigger your router.

Then, all your router does is hide all the Sections except the selected one whenever triggered. If there's no selection, it just shows the first one!

I'm not 100% sure of this strategy, but this is definitely "the Backbone way". Let me know if I can clear anything up.